# Ansible Run Command As Another User

Tags: linux, ansible

I know my question is what `become` is designed to solve. And I do use it. However, my command seems to still be run as the ssh user. I'm trying to execute a `which psql` command to get the executable path. Running `which psql` as ssh user gives a different output than running the same command as my become user which is the output I want.

**EDIT** The problem is the $PATH variable ansible is using as suggested in comments. It is not using the correct $PATH variable. How can I direct ansible to use `postgres` users $PATH variable? Using environment module didn't work for me as suggested here https://serverfault.com/questions/734560/ansible-become-user-not-picking-up-path-correctly

**EDIT2** So a solution is to use the environment module and set the path to the path I know has the psql executable but this seems hacky. Ideally, I'd like to just be able to use the become users path and not have to explicitly set it. Here's the hacky solution:

```
- name: Check if new or existing host
  command: which psql
  environment:
    PATH: "/usr/pgsql-13/bin/:{{ansible_env.PATH}}"
  become: yes
  become_user: postgres
```

Playbook

```
---
- name: Playbook Control
  hosts: all
  become: yes
  become_user: postgres

  tasks:
    - name: Check if new or existing host
      shell: whoami && which psql
      register: output
```

Relevant Output (the same as if I were to run the task command as my_user on myhost.net)

```
"stdout_lines": [
    "postgres",
    "/usr/bin/psql"
]
```

Expected Output (the output if I were to run the task command as postgres user on myhost.net)

```
"stdout_lines": [
    "postgres",
    "/usr/pgsql-13/bin/psql"
]
```

Inventory

```
myhost.net 

[all:vars]
ansible_connection=ssh
ansible_user=my_user
```

Command

```
ansible-playbook --ask-vault-pass  -vvv -i temp_hosts playbook.yml
```

In vault I only have the ssh pass of my_user.

Running the playbook with `-vvv` flag shows me that escalation was successful and that the output of this task is the output of running the command as ssh user, not become user. Any ideas?

Comment: Smells like you may be getting bitten by [variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#ansible-variable-precedence), but with the anemic amount of detail in your post, who can know

Comment: What other info can I provide?

Comment: @cap what is the task current output, what is the output you expect, what is in your inventory, how do you launch that playbook, are details you should add to make your question a [mre].

Comment: Probably this user has something in its `$PATH` or in a `.bashrc` that makes it acts like that when you do have an interactive shell but not with the shell used by Ansible.

Comment: Also, is the same task launched with Ansible with and without `become` giving you the same? i.e. is the path to that executable the same in an interactive shell and in the output of Ansible for the user `my_user`?

Comment: Same executable path with or without `become`. And as far as I can tell, `.bashrc` is only setting env variables

Comment: Is there a way to force ansible to use the same shell I would use?

Comment: @cap not _"the same shell as you would use"_. But you can force Ansible to use a specific binary for the shell, yes: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html#parameter-executable

Answer (score 1):

Ansible by default uses `sudo` as the default `become` method.
Depending on how your linux system is configured (check `/etc/sudoers`), it could be that your `$PATH` variable is preserved for sudo commands.

You can either change this, or force ansible to use a different `become` method such as `su`:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#become-directives